# Multi Requests break same class instance during execution

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, race-condition

I have a class played as cache which uses a Map (either HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap), I'd like to clear my Map before executing each new (http) request, e.g

```
@Component
public Class MyCache {
   Map cache = new ConcurrentHashMap();
   
   get(key) {
      cache.computeIfAbsent(key, fetchFromDB())
   }
   clearCache() {
      cache.clear()
   }
}

@Controller
public Class MyController {
   @Autowired
   MyCache myCache
   
   @Get
   Response getInfo(ids) {
      // give me a fresh cache at beginning of every new request
      myCache.clearCache()
      // load and fetch from myCache of current request
      ids.foreach(id -> {
          myCache.get(id)
      })
   }
}
```

Above code idea is to

- initially reset cache when a new request comes in
- then for all id of input(could be hundreds), fetch from cache
- if same id already stored in cache, we don't need to re-call fetchFromDB.

Everything works locally with single thread, but when calling with 2 or more threads, there are chances that during the execution of thread1, thread2 started and it would call `myCache.clearCache()`, somehow my thread1 suddenly found nothing stored in myCache anymore for all its processed items.

- The reason is because my map was in class as singleton (e.g MyCache, Controller), while even each request deals with its own thread, they will take action on same instance
- What's the best way that I would fix this issue if I still wants to get a clean cache for each request comes in? Anyway I can detect if there might be other threads still executing before my current thread clearCache()

Comment: Why are you sharing the cache if you want a clean slate for each request? Just create a regular map and keep it on the request scope.

Comment: Each http request is handled in its own thread but there is only one `MyController` instance shared by all threads and with the current design only one `MyCache` instance (because it is referenced by field in `MyController`)

Comment: @ThomasKläger correct but how should I fix that? Because of singleton scope I believe even multiple requests generate multithreads, it all access same instance. I have also tried using prototype on my cache class but it's same behavior. Reason would be like you mentioned, controller is singleton

Comment: @shmosel the root cause here is not hashmap vs concurrent hashmap, but the class scope that wraps with the map

Comment: I didn't say it's the root cause. I'm saying you shouldn't need a concurrent map because you shouldn't be sharing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by following how Google Guava Cache works with Concurrent Hashmap and Reentrance lock as Segment